# Правила выделения целевых меток на изображения набора данных в машинном обучении

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

знатоки машинного обучения, можете, пожалуйста, сказать **какие целевые метки** на фотографиях ниже будут **правильные**, а какие **неправильные** и **почему**?

Хочу научить нейросеть распозновать машины. И возникают вопросы, видя такие экземпляры в наборе данных, где машину перекрывает дерево, или часть машины на 1/5 находится за кадром. И как отмечать целевую метку в таком случае - не понятно.

Фото 1 (машина частично перекрыта ветками).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото 2 (мешает трава).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото 3 (1/4 машины просто скрыта за кадром)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от ваших целей. Если модель должна определять присутствует ли на картинке машина, то речь идет о **бинарной** классификации и метками у вас будут единицы и нули - `1` - есть машина на картинке, `0` - нет машины на картинке.

Для такой модели все приведенные в вопросе картинки должны иметь метку `1` (машина присутствует на картинке).

---

Если вам надо определять тип или марку машины, то целевые метки соответственно должны представлять правильный тип/марку машины. В этом случае речь идет о **мультиклассовой** классификации.

Comment: спасибо! А можете еще сказать, пожалуйста, правильными ли будут эти картинки в случае мультиклассовой или multilabel классификации?

Comment: Это будет правильным для любой классификации в принципе, просто рассматривайте у себя в голове эти картинки как немного кропнутые и т.д.